# Get value from outside ng-repeat in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can i get a value from outside an ng-repeat?
This is my function to get values from json

```
function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('https://www.mywebsite.com/images/getimages.php').
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.walls = data.walls;
            console.log($scope.walls);
         }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
         });
```

then i have a table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="wall in walls">
                <td>{{wall.id}}</td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="">{{wall.link}}</a></td>            
            </tr>
```

i would show in a div outside the table and so outside the ng-repeat, the {{wall.link}} selected from the td. How can i do it?

Comment: not clear what you want to show outside the table?

Comment: This value: {{wall.link}} that i select. Assuming that i have 5 rows. When i click in the 3rd row i want show in a div outside the ng-repeat that item i clicked. so {{wall.link}} of 3rd row. Understand now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement controller function to set selected wall object:

```
function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('https://www.mywebsite.com/images/getimages.php')
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { /*...*/ })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { /*...*/ });

    $scope.select = function (wall) {
        $scope.selectedWall = wall;
    };
}
```

and the in HTML you would use

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="wall in walls">
        <td>{{wall.id}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="select(wall)">{{wall.link}}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div>{{selectedWall.link}}</div>
```